# SSE and EventEmitter in NestJS - How to use observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, nestjs, observable

I want to omit an event that happens in the backend and show it in the frontend. I dont need sockets here because its a one way communication. So I want to try to push the event thats omitted towards the frontend using SSE (Server sent events) in nestjs.
Now the setup is pretty simple according to the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events):

```js
@Sse('sse')
sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
  return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } })));
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, and it works. However, this should now just push the "event" thats happening in the backend, instead of using `interval` etc.

Here is my current setup:

```js
@Injectable()
export class StocksService {
  public stocks: Stock[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      symbol: 'Stock #1',
      bid: 500,
      ask: 500,
    }
  ];

  constructor(private eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) {}

  create(createStockDto: CreateStockDto) {
    const stock = {
      id: this.stocks.length + 1,
      ...createStockDto,
    };
    this.stocks.push(stock);

    const stockCreatedEvent = new StockCreatedEvent();
    stockCreatedEvent.symbol = stock.symbol;
    stockCreatedEvent.ask = stock.ask;
    stockCreatedEvent.bid = stock.bid;

    this.eventEmitter.emit('stock.created', stockCreatedEvent);

    return stock;
  }
}
```

Now `this.eventEmitter.emit('stock.created', stockCreatedEvent);` emits the event and I can console log it using a small listener, and see it just fine:

```js
@Injectable()
export class StockCreatedListener {
  @OnEvent('stock.created')
  handleStockCreatedEvent(event: StockCreatedEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

So now, whenever I hit the service with Postman and create a Stock entry, it will console log the event, which is great! Now I want this data pushed towards the frontend using SSE.

However, after digging through the RxJS docs, I am not sure I understand how I am supposed to connect these two.
I know I need to make an `Observable`, which I tried with:

```js
  @Sse('sse')
  @OnEvent('stock.created')
  sse(event: StockCreatedEvent): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    const obj = of(event);
    return obj.pipe(map((_) => ({ data: event})));
  }
```

However, even if i go to the url `http://localhost:3000/sse` it will not do anything, even not console logging or returning any stream.
Do i need an observable here.. or a subject?

Please help a brother out. [Here](https://github.com/Thorbenl/nestjs-stocks) is also the repo, if you need to look at it a bit more specifically

Answer (score 3):

I'm creating something similar.

I needed to send an SSE signal to connected clients only when an asset had its price updated. Used a webhook instead of short polling.

The solution was achieved in a similar way as below (I removed the least important parts):

**`LiveQuoteController`:**

```js
//... other imports
import { EventEmitter2 } from "@nestjs/event-emitter";
import { Observable, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Controller("/livequote")
export class LiveQuoteController {
    constructor (private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) {}

    @Sse()
    public liveQuote(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
        return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter, "price.update")
            .pipe(map(price => {
                return { data: price } as MessageEvent;
            }));
    }
}
```

**`PriceUpdateHookController`:**

```js
//... other imports
import { EventEmitter2 } from "@nestjs/event-emitter";

@Controller("/price")
export class PriceUpdateHookController {
    constructor (private readonly eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) { }

    @Post()
    updatePrice(@Body() newPrice: number) {
        this.eventEmitter.emit("price.update", newPrice);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `http://localhost:3000/sse`
in React `App.tsx` at line 6.

It works for me.

### client side

From

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://0.0.0.0:3000/sse');
```

To

```
  const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/sse');
```

### server side

It display same message, I just changed current time at server side.
In `app.controller.ts`,

From

```
  sse(event: StockCreatedEvent): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } })));
  }
```

To

```
  sse(event: StockCreatedEvent): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world, time = ' +  new Date().toUTCString() } })));
  }
```

Result

`server side` - backend (nestjs)

[image]

`client side` - client (React)

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. but were u able to push the event further? `sse(event: StockCreatedEvent)` this event needs to be pushed to the frontend. The hello world example works for me too, but i cant push the `event` further, which is the problem here. Sorry if that wasnt clear in the initial post

Comment: I mean like this: 
```
    return event.pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } })));
  }
```

but i think in order to do that i need to convert the event into an observeable or subject or something

Comment: @TLListenreich, you changed whole question - I can't figure out your problem with current update, I needs full your source code. can you push it your github account?

Comment: it is linked in the bottom of the question.

Comment: It is not include `StockCreatedListener`. I am talking about your code.